# Use method with default parameter in map

Tags: scala, currying

I want to map a stream of `Doubles` to a method which takes two parameters, one of them has a default value. I want to use the default parameter so my method has only 1 parameter which I need to pass:

```
  def pow(x:Double, exponent:Double=2.0) = {
    math.pow(x,exponent)
  }
```

I've found out that the following works, but I do not understand why:

```
  val res = (1 to 100).map(_.toDouble).map(pow(_))
```

I'm especially confused because the following does not work (compiler error because of missing type information):

```
  val pow2 = pow(_)
  val res = pow2(2.0)
  println(res) // expect 4.0
```

Comment: The compiler is not able to interfere the type provided for pow2 clearly. If you say val pow2 = pow(_:Double) the example works.

Comment: What scala version do you use (mine is 2.11.8 REPL) ? Unable to reproduce behavior, `val pow2 = pow(_)` gets compile error `missing parameter type`. If I write `val pow2: Double => Double  = x => pow(x)`, everything works.

Comment: sorry you are right, its not a runtime error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is not able to infer the type that you will provide to `pow2`. In the `res` mapping you explicitly feed it a collection of `Doubles`and therefore `pow(_)` does not complain. However, in the case of `val pow2 = pow(_)` it complains that type parameter is missing. Change it to

```
val pow2 = pow(_: Double)
val res = pow2(2.0)
println(res)
```

and it will work just fine. `pow(_)` will be expanded two `x => pow(x)` and at this point the compiler cannot infere what's `x` without the type annotation.

Comment: I do not really understand what `pow(_)` does because `pow` takes two arguments. Can you comment that?

Comment: `val pow2 = pow(_)`  is shorthand for `val pow2: Double => Double = x => pow(x)`, if you write types explicitly.

Comment: What @dveim said. Without the type annotation `pow(_)` you tell the compiler "Here is `pow` function, I will give you some `_` parameter later" but you don't tell it what type it will be. You might give it a conflicting one, say `String` or a correct one `Double`. The error is a safeguard against the former case.